# Counter inside iterate smarty loop

Tags: smarty, iteration, loops

I have this smarty code :

```
{iterate from=fruits item=fruit}
 ....
{/iterate}
```

I want to have a counter inside this loop that accept a start value and increase by one until the loop continues.

I should i use? i am not good in smarty.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `.iteration`

```
{foreach from=fruits item=fruit}
 current item #: {$smarty.foreach.fruits.iteration}
{/foreach}
```

source: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.index

Answer (score 3):

In case you have something like this:

```
{foreach from=$fruits item=fruit} {/foreach}
```

Instead of this:

```
{foreach from=fruits item=fruit} {/foreach}
```

You should use this syntax:

```
{foreach from=$fruits item=fruit name=counter} 
    Iteration no {$smarty.foreach.counter.iteration}
{/foreach}
```